# Keep only filename with regex

Tags: mysql, regex, wordpress

I'm currently trying to solve the problem I encountered while migrating old website to WordPress. The files on the website had a hierarchy tree, but I'm not using that hierarchy on the new WordPress website, so I need to replace with regex the old with the new one, the example below:
URL I Have:

`/wp-content/uploads/files/poradenstvo/aktuality/2017/racioenergia/thumbs/file_name.jpg`

URL I Want:

`/wp-content/uploads/file_name.jpg`

I already tried to using somethings like this:
https://regex101.com/r/gO6xD8/160

but sadly it Is not working as expected.

Comment: You should describe the problem in little more detail such as this is expected to work on html file content as you have shown in the link. For now can you give this a try: ``\/wp-content\/uploads\/files\/.*?\/([\w._]+\.[\w]{1,5})``

Comment: As there are thousands of URL's linked in WordPress articles/pages, I'm using a plugin called "Regex Search" to globally change the URL structure of the linked files, so that is why regex is needed. The structure is different as there are multiple folders and subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regex:

`(\/wp-content\/uploads\/).+\/(.+?\..+)`

then replace with `\1\2`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gO6xD8/164)